# OnClick: differentiate Parent div from Child div

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am currently working on a website but I am completely new to HTML and JQuery.

I currently have the following Website:[image: Prototype Front-end]

Here is the HTML code produce dynamically using JQuery:

```html
<div class="gallery-card" id="SOME_ID" onclick="ViewSelected(this.id)" style="background-color: rgb(206, 20, 186);">
  <strong class="StrongClass">Carlos Ba</strong>
  <button class="Gallery-Button" onclick="TakeToCardInfo(this.id)" id="SOME_ID">See More..</button>
  <div class="circle" onclick="DeleteRecordAction(this.id)" id="SOME_ID">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-sizeB"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My desired functionality is that when the user clicks on the **gallery-card div's** (which are the squares with names), the user sees the details of the selected gallery-card and that when the user clicks on the circles with x's, the respective gallery-card is deleted. Right now, this functionality is partly working. Whenever I click on any part of the **gallery-card div**, the correct selected gallery-card info is displayed BUT when I click on the circles with x's, instead of simply deleting the record, it also tries to display the deleted record. How do I prevent this? How do I prevent the behavior of the Parent (**Gallery-card div**) from activating when the user clicks on the child element (**div class="Circle**)?

Comment: Make the circle an anchor or button instead of a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event object to the function, and call `event.stopPropagation()` to keep the event from bubbling out to the container.

```
onclick="DeleteRecordAction(this.id, event)"
```

And change `DeleteRecordAction` to something like:

```
function DeleteRecordAction(id, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // rest of code
}
```

BTW, rather than passing `this.id` to the function, just pass `this`. Then you don't need to call `getElementById()` to get back the element, you can just use the parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much!